# Hortonworks Data Platform HDP 2.1 start Namenode Error

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I have installed `HDP 2.1.1.0` in `SUSE11 VM`. I am receiving the following error when trying to start the namenode for the first time after formatting:

> /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/../libexec/hdfs-config.sh: No such file or
>   directory
>
> /usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/bin/hdfs: line 206: exec: : not found

Please suggest some resolution for the same.

FYI: I have updated libexec path details in .bashrc file as well. Still getting the same issue.

Comment: Which installation guide did you follow while installation ?

Comment: @did you try running sudo command

Comment: I followed the Installation guide available in HDP site to install HDP 2.x manually... [HDP Installation GUIDE](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.1-latest/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap5-4.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found that while installing Hadoop rpm from HDP 2.1 repository, the libexec folder was not copied in Hadoop-HDFS folder in usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs

So I exported the Path of libexec, which was residing in /usr/lib/**hadoop**/libexec in my .bashrc file and it works fine now.